# Scroll to top and refresh page after user stopped scrolling

Tags: javascript

I'm showcasing a web project in a museum setting. It's a project that relies heavy on scrolling, and needs to be reset between users. I want to set up a timer that will scroll the page to the top and reload after a user has walked away from the computer. I did some research and this is what I have settled on so far. It resets the page if the user has not scrolled after two minutes:

```
// Setup isScrolling variable
let isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {

    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(() => {

    // scroll to top and refresh page
    console.log('Scrolling has stopped.');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    location.reload();

    }, 120000);

}, false);
```

Is this the best way to solve this problem? Will running an event listener on every scroll be super intensive, or is this pretty much the way to do it?

Comment: This should probably be posted in Code Review. But why are you calling `scrollTo(0,0)` just before a `location.reload()`? The page refresh would already reset the page, right?

Comment: The reason I'm calling it before is because I need to scroll the page to the top before the reload. If i just do the reload, the page will still be at the same location as before it was reloaded. I'll check out code review, thanks.

Comment: Id think from a *use case* / design perspective - you need to make sure the user isn't looking at something they scrolled down to, as priority. Putting an overlay up at timeout that indicates "are you lurking, or are do you want the original content" is probably more effective than just snapping the screen up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok.  One thing you could consider is a debounce:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

This would prevent setting a new timeout on every single scroll event.